# How can I specify a Stored Procedure to be used in the SSRS Report Wizard?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, connection-string, bids

In a BIDS project, after selecting Reports > Add New Report, and adding a connection string as the Shared Data Source in the Report Wizard, the wizard next prompts for a query (in the "Design the Query" page of the wizard).

I want to specify an existing Stored Procedure. How can I do that? Is it possible to specify it directly in the connection string? e.g, I provided something like this as the connection string:

```
SERVER=GoCards2016;DATABASE=platypusdata;UID=duckbill;PWD=dannyAndTheJuniors;Connection Timeout=0
```

Can I also insert the Stored Procedure to use in there somewhere?

Or do I need to enter a bogus query in the "Design the Query" page of the wizard and later replace it in the .rdl (xml) file with the Stored Procedure name? Or...???

Comment: why don't you use the `EXEC` statement? `exec my_stored_procedure`

Comment: Sounds reasonable; I was able to change the Command Type from Text to Stored Procedure on the Data pane after clicking through the wizard, and that works, too. If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it, because that's probably better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Report Wizard will let you only use Query strings so you can't select a stored procedure, but You can use the `EXEC` statement to specify a stored procedure to run.

```
exec my_stored_procedure_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Click through the wizard, then, in the "Data" tab, change the Command Type from Text to Stored Procedure and enter the name of your Stored Procedure.

So, with a little more specific instructions:

In the “Design the Query” page of the wizard, either enter “Exec [sp name]” or just enter some temporary query such as “select * from [tableName]” and then, once the Report Wizard has completed, in the data tab of the report, change the “Command type:” dropdown from Text to “Stored Procedure” and then enter the name of the Stored Procedure below.

Mash the “!” (Run) button to generate the data.

Answer (score 1):

- Open Reports
- In Solution Explorer Right Click on Reports
- Click on Add New Report
- Click on Next
- Select the Data source and click on Next
- Click on Query Builder button
- Click on "Edit As Text"
- In Command Type Select StoredProcedure
- Enter the Stored Procedure Name ONLY in the text box
- Click OK. The window should close
- Click Next
- Configure
- Finish

From: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ddcb6a4-03f8-461e-9caa-01c058812f01/using-stored-procedure-with-report-wizard?forum=sqlreportingservices